# Some questions' titles not shown (Safari only)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Sometimes I see a question that, when seen from the homepage, appears to have no title. You can still click its box and go to the question's page, where the title is visible.

In the below screencap, the effected question is #11664.

This isn't a problem from Chrome, but it is from WebKit nightly builds and Safari.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I'm using Safari 5.0.4 (5533.20.27) OSX.

Comment: @Jin Figured out why. It's caused by an [extension](http://babelstudios.se/defacer/) I've got that hides Facebook 'Like' buttons on other sites. For some reason, it's giving that link a `display:none !important;`. So, I guess that makes it a problem on my end. Sorry for false alarm.

Comment: @Jin given ^, should I just delete this question? I feel kinda silly for not looking into that kind of thing ahead of time...

Comment: I'll just mark it as status-norepro